# How to make such database record in php mysql such that A inform B,B inform C,and C inform D such that when I look at who A answer should be B,C,D?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

How to make such database record in php mysql such that A inform B,B inform C,and C inform D such that when I look at who A answer should be B,C,D?

Comment: u mean like TraceChaining ? So ask for the Origin and it gives u back A ?

Comment: yes Like hierarchy system.

Comment: Hierarchical as described here: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/ ?

Answer (score 1):

A table like this

```
'name'   'inform_to'
A        B
B        c
C        D
D        Null
```

And you can check always recursively check till the value of column is not `Null`

Comment: u can also use a 3rd column to set the origin so u can directly call from a child where it came from